# Stopping textFieldDidEndEditing being called when quitting out of viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a ViewController with a TextField for user input and a Quit button in a NavigationBar.

Normally, the user inputs text into the textField and the input is processed in `textFieldDidEndEditing`. If the Quit button is tapped before editing starts, then it segues correctly to the parent ViewController.

However, if editing has started on the textField and then the Quit button is tapped, `textFieldDidEndEditing` is still called, which I don't want to happen.

I have tried using `textFieldDidEndEditing:reason:` but the returned reason in both cases is `UITextFieldDidEndEditingReasonCommitted`. It seems that `UITextFieldDidEndEditingReasonCancelled` is only valid in tvOS not iOS.

How else can I detect that the user has Quit and prevent `textFieldDidEndEditing` from running to completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent `textFieldDidEndEditing` from being called. Dismissing the view controller dismisses the text field. Since the text field is no longer being edited, the delegate method will be called.

One option you have is to set a flag when the user taps the Quit button. Then in your implementation of `textFieldDidEndEditing` you can check if that flag it set or not and act accordingly.

Comment: @maddy - I had a different segue at the end of the textFieldDidEndEditing method and using  NSlog in the destinations of the two segues had indicated that the one at the end of textFieldDidEndEditing was being executed before the one in the Quit method, so I was sceptical that setting a flag in the Quit method would work. But surprisingly it does! Many thanks for guiding me to the answer.